# Get list of target Platform programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, target-platform

How can I get a list of available target definitions for a workspace programmatically? I am writing a plugin that requires to display the list of all available target platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ITargetPlatformService` OSGi service provides information about the target platforms.

Get this with something like:

```
ServiceReference<ITargetPlatformService> ref = bundleContext.getService(ITargetPlatformService.class);

ITargetPlatformService service = bundleContext.getService(ref);
```

where `bundleContext` is the `BundleContext` passed to the `start` method of your plugin's activator.

Call the

```
public ITargetHandle[] getTargets(IProgressMonitor monitor)
```

method of `ITargetPlatformService` to get an array of the target platforms.

Comment: Thanks  @greg. How would I get a reference of the BundleContext outside of the Activator?

Comment: I used the FrameowrkUtil class to get the bundle context but now I am unable to find how to get the monitor when calling getTargets

Comment: You can probably use `null` for the monitor or `NullProgressMonitor`.

Comment: Yea I used NullProgressMonitor. Thanks. But its not pulling all the target platforms, just the running target platform. I am using service.getTargets(new NullProgressMonitor()); where service is the ITargetPlatformService

Comment: Don't forget that when you use 'Run > Eclipse Application' to test a plugin that a new test Eclipse is started. You get the target platforms in the test Eclipse (not your main development Eclipse). You need to set up target platforms in the test Eclipse.

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much @greg. I was wondering whats wrong with my code. ahah You are awesome :)